# Is My Load Bearing Beam Safe?

Tags: kitchens, load-bearing, engineering

I have been getting work done on my kitchen which involved removing a load bearing wall. To make a long story short, the contractor is a liar and now I can’t trust him. It has been 2 months now of trying to get the beam approved by inspection. As a part of the permit process we did have to submit a plan from a structural engineer, which I have, but as far as I am aware, the structural engineer has never actually been to my house and has been contacted only by the contractor, not by me. I’m living about 2 hours away right now making things very difficult. Point is, I don’t know enough about engineering to know if this is safe or not. How could an engineer calculate the load of my house without ever seeing it?

Any replies from any engineers with feedback would be great.

Comment: An engineer dies not have to see it. He/She just needs dimensions and a sketch.

Comment: Did you see the Plan?  Did the plan look close enough to the house with the same dimensions?  Did the builder go by the plan?

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate here since it's ultimately about human nature, but if your contractor isn't providing accurate information to the engineer, how can the engineer's judgement be reliable? You knew that before you stopped by. FYI, engineers almost never visit jobsites in residential construction. They work from drawings almost exclusively from the comfort of their office chairs.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty simple.

The work must be done according to the plan (drawings) made by the engineer.

The engineer does not have to go to your home.

Work that is done must pass inspection by your local building department.

If that work has not, or cannot pass inspection, you will have to speak with the local building department as to why.  They can tell you if the beam is not sufficient,( not built according to the engineered drawing) or if the attachment is not done correctly, or why they will not pass that part of the construction process.  Then you will have the correct information.

In the event that the inspector and the contractor have a disagreement, then schedule a meeting with them both and yourself at the home to discuss what will need to be done to make all parties satisfied so the project can move on.

Comment: 99% agree, except to say that the building department doesn’t have the scope to have an opinion about a stamped engineered drawing. (In other words, if the engineer says a 2x6 is sufficient and the building inspector disagrees, the engineer wins every time.) Now, the building inspector has plenty of other pathways to make trouble for a job, so any sane GC works *with*, not against the inspector.

Comment: I edited the answer.  I agree the inspector does not opine about the beam other than if it is correct according to the drawing.

Comment: Also, having the inspector say "no, this isn't correct" gives the OP the firepower he needs to get the contractor to move or, worst case, to win in court. If it's just "Joe Average" homeowner against the contractor, the contractor is going to win 99.99% of the time.